# Problem connecting Galaxy Note 10.1 to Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: file-transfer, macos

I'm trying to connect my Galaxy Note 10.1 (running Android 4.2.2) to my Mac OS 10.8 machine via USB. I used Android File Transfer, but it gives me an error that says:

> Could not connect to device. Try reconnecting or restarting your device.

Comment: I more time search answer for this question and found this: http://playaprogrammer.blogspot.com/2013/01/using-android-file-transfer-with.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason of my problem. Before installing Android File Transfer i installed KIES. After installing AFT i uninstall the KIES. i understand that when  i uninstall the KIES uninstall USB driver too. So installed KIES again and AFT is working!!! Its really cool application!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the USB Connection mode to Camera (PTP) mode or Media device (MTP) mode? Might help to deinstall KIES. The USB cable does work on another laptop/pc?